# how to remove link to resource list view from menu?

Tags: react-admin

I'm currently building out an application that has a boatload of resources that i will need list views of but don't want links to the list views in the menu. Is there a way to have access to them without having links on the side? to create the list i'm doing the following.

```
<resources
 list={EmployeeList}
 />
```

docs don't mention this so any help would be appreciated.

I have say ~45 resources that i will need to access list views but only 6 or so are major enough to be accessed from the main menu. i'd still want access to them by viewing details of the other lists or show pages.

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue to receive a detailed answer. How exactly do you want to 'have access to them without having links on the side'?
Maybe via the url? i.e. type "YOUR_APP/employee"? and go to the employees' list but you don't want the 'Employees' button on your menu?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want to happen. i want to be able to go to the url but don't want the button in the menu.

Comment: Ok, in that case I think your only option is to create a custom menu and provide it to your Admin component, as react-admin is not that modular on its default menu.

Comment: Note that menu option is deprecated and you should create a custom layout in which you'll have your custom menu as described here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-layout

Comment: alright thanks. that's what i was thinking i'd need to do. have a nice day.

Comment: There are plenty examples on how to create a custom menu starting from the official documentation and here. If you need further help just ask

Comment: Still in late 2021 you have to do a custom menu to hide resources in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure how or where you need to access these resources, but this is what I've done with some "lesser" resources I don't need to have the "List" view or sidebar link to:

Define
`<Resource name="myresource" />`

in App.js. Now you can make a list for example inside another resource's "show" view by using `<ReferenceManyField resource="myresource" />`